# Rider2020 build project cannot be hot reloaded with Unreal Engine 4.25

Tags: unreal-engine4, rider

My Rider IDE version is R4UE 2020.2 (202.5958.481)，I have installed the required RiderLink plug-in and RiderSourceCodeAccess plug-in, and I have configured "Development Editor | Win64", but whenever I modify the code and build the project, Unreal Editor does not respond, I can only manually click Compile in Unreal Editor .

And if Unreal Editor is running and I build the project in Rider IDE, a prompt box will pop up, which says "The build might fail as some files may be locked by active run/debug session.", and there are two Options , "Build" and "Stop and Build". If I click on "Build", as I said above, Unreal Editor will not respond. If I click on "Stop and Build", Unreal Editor will end. But after I restarted Unreal Editor through Rider IDE, I found that my changed code did not take effect. I mean no matter which option I click, I have to click compile in Unreal Editor to be useful

And, no matter how much code I modify, building projects in Rider is very fast, almost instantaneously. Is this normal? please help me